# @Transient sobreescribe el ultimo dato a toda la lista

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo un problema con una propiedad de tipo `@Transient`, primero en el codigo de abajo, hago un forEach para recorrer cada producto contenido en la lista, por cada uno, calculo sus precios (en la clase de tipo Precio), dentro de esa clase tengo una propiedad `tiposPrecio`, el problema es que en todos los productos solo se me guarda el ultimo array de `Precios` consultado.

Trate de vaciar la propiedad luego de añadirla con add al response, pero al hacer esto todos los precios van en null en el response, **¿alguien ha tenido este problema?**,**¿Como puedo solucionar?**, como mencione la propiedad que tiene el problema es `@Transient`, sin relacion

```java
productos.forEach(p -> {
    
    ProductoResponse producto = new ProductoResponse();
    
    List<ProductoResponse> response = new ArrayList<ProductoResponse>();

    // Siempre me trae precios diferentes, aqui no se duplican
    List<Precio> precios = preciosService.findByProductoId(p.getId());


    producto.setPrecios(precios); 
    producto.setIdProducto(p.getId());
    producto.setNombre(p.getNombre);
    response.add(producto);

    // linea para vaciar los precios, ocasiona que todos los precios vayan en null
    precios.forEach(precio -> precio.setTiposPrecio(new PreciosProducto()));
})
```

Clase Precios

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRECIOS")
public class Precio{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "N_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    private transient PreciosProducto tiposPrecio;

    @Transient
    public PreciosProducto getTiposPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    @Transient
    public void setTiposPrecio(PreciosProducto tiposPrecio) {
        this.tiposPrecio = tiposPrecio;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que en la entidad Precio solo tienes mapeado el atributo id con el campo N_ID de la base de datos, y tienes excluido lo demás.

La anotación @Transident lo que hace es excluir ese atributo del mapeo de la entidad con la tabla.

Tienes que quitar el @Transident de PreciosProducto y por supuesto del get y set,  poner la relación correspondiente que podría ser @OneToMany.

https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/